# Undefined + HTML Form Name added to URL for HTML / JQuery URL Appending

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a dashboard for myself and fellow employees to use. One of the features I'd like to add is a form that would allow us to add a Ticket number, hit "Submit" and then be forwarded to the desired Ticket. For this to work, I need the Ticket Number to be added to the end of the URL.

Code

```
<form id="tix" onsubmit="pulltix()">
    <input id="tix1" name="tix1" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
<form>

<script>

function pulltix() {

var action_src = $("tix1").val();

var urlLink = "https://www.ourtixsystem.com/tixnumber/";
var urlLink = urlLink + action_src;

srs.action = urlLink;

}
```

When I press submit, it is forwarding to our Ticket system but I get an error message. Reason being is that the following is added to the URL:

https://www.ourticketingsystem.com/tixnumber/**undefined?tix1=12345**

It looks like I have two issues here. One, I'm not defining something but I don't know what. And Two, "tix1=12345" can't be in the URL.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Typo.  `$('tix1')` should be `$('#tix1')` to be an id selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is submitting to the ticket page using a `GET` request. This will append form values to the query string. You can either use javascript to redirect or when submitting the form, adjust the action and disable the form field, this will prevent the form field from being submitted.

Your problem with **undefined** is you are not using the correct jQuery selector. You need to use the ID selector `$("#tix1").val();` note the addition of **#**

**Option 1: -Redirect on button click**

```js
function pulltix() {

  var action_src = $("#tix1").val();
  var srs = $("#tix");
  var urlLink = "https://www.ourtixsystem.com/tixnumber/";
  var urlLink = urlLink + action_src;  
  console.log(urlLink);
  location.href = urlLink;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="tix" >
  <input id="tix1" name="tix1" type="text">
  <input type="button" onclick="pulltix()" value="Submit">
<form>
```

**Option 2: - Submit form, disable field**

```js
function pulltix() {

  var action_src = $("#tix1").val();
  var srs = $("#tix");
  var urlLink = "https://www.ourtixsystem.com/tixnumber/";
  var urlLink = urlLink + action_src;  
  srs.action = urlLink;
  
  //Disable the form field
  $("#tix1").prop("disabled", true);
  
  
  //THE FOLLOWING 2 LINES ARE FOR DEBUGGIN ONLY
  //REMOVE ON YOUR SYSTEM
  console.log(srs.action);
  return false;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="tix" onsubmit="pulltix()">
  <input id="tix1" name="tix1" type="text">
  <input type="submit">
  <form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<form id="tix" action = "https://www.ourtixsystem.com" method = "POST">
    <input id="tix1" name="tix1" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
<form>
```

Use form directly, if you want to post just some basic fields, you do not have to call JavaScript function.

You are using default method of sending data that is `get`, which adds data in URL, use `POST` to send data in the body instead of the request